# Export https to express routes for use in new WebSocket

Tags: node.js, express, websocket

im attempting to export the following with module.exports = httpsSv;

main.js

```
const https = require("https");
const express = require("express");

const app = express();
const httpsSv = https.createServer({
    key: fs.readFileSync("./key.pem"),
    cert: fs.readFileSync("./cert.pem"),
    passphrase: "12345"
}, app).listen(port, () => {console.log(`Server started on port ${port}`)});

const appRoute = require("./routes/app");
app.use("/", appRoute);

module.exports = httpsSv;
```

I passed an express application to the https server and would like to use the https server in a file for express routes, i have required the ws (websocket) npm package in the file, im hoping to be able to pass the https server as the server parameter with:

routes/app.js

```
const express = require("express");
const { httpsSv } = require("../main");

const router = express.Router();

var wss = new webSocket.Server({server: httpsSv, path: "/app"});
wss.on("connection", (ws) => {
    console.log("Client connected")
})

// Bunch of other routes for the main app, exported using the usual:
module.exports = router;
```

unfortunately the https server i passed is undefined, what would it take to pass it successfully, and is this is good way to go about websockets? don't necessarily know how to organize them, putting them in express route files is the best way i could think of doing it, im very confused and would like to know how to do this properly, thanks

Comment: If it's `undefined`, then you apparently aren't importing or exporting it properly or you have created a circular loop where A imports B and B imports A (which is something you can't do if using `require()`).  For folks to help you, we will probably need to see a larger context of code including all relevant import and export code in these two modules.

Comment: @jfriend00 ill try to include more details, updated the post, im guessing thats a circular loop thats contributing to the problem?

Comment: Whoops, i solved the problem by setting the https server to be a global variable (global.httpsSv) and not exporting it, nor importing it, just reference it in the app.js as it has already been imported to main.js, sorry for the flawed logic, thanks for your help

Comment: You can post your solution as an answer

Comment: Using a global is a very bad idea.  You should learn how to use module import and export correctly.  See my answer below that explains why it wasn't working for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line:

```
const { httpsSv } = require("../main");
```

is not consistent with the way you are exporting it here:

```
module.exports = httpsSv;
```

`module.exports = httpsSv;` is exporting the `httpsSv` object directly as your only export object.  But, `const { httpsSv } = require("../main");` is expecting you to export an object that has an `httpsSv` property.  So, the export and the import are not doing it the same way.

---

You can use either of these two options:

```
module.exports = { httpsSv };
// with
const { httpsSv } = require("../main");
```

or

```
module.exports = httpsSv;
// with
const httpsSv = require("../main");
```

Please note the symmetry between the export and the import.

Comment: Yes, could you please explain on why global variables are unfit for use? does it become an attack vector? i couldn't figure out how to access it without making it a global variable, when i try and use the first option, WebSocket (ws module) complains that a port or server must be specified, the second option complains "server.on is not a function" both a TypeError

Comment: @Arsha - Global variables are the anti-matter to good, modular, testable, sharable code.  Do not use them.  There is no problem in node.js that requires a global variable and can't be solved with proper module design.  To give you one example, if you have a module that relies on a global variable set by some other module that it doesn't explicitly depend on, then that module can't be independently tested.  If you do that a lot in your project, then pretty soon nothing can be independently tested as everything requires your entire app infrastructure to actually test anything.

Comment: Also didn't realize i goofed up in main.js and didn't export before including route middleware.